# abi_tab on operator std::string(): incompatibilities in clang++ and g++

Tags: c++11, g++, clang++

Take simple code:

```
#include <string>

class C{
public:
  operator std::string ()const;
};

C c;

std::string foo(){return c;}


bool bar(std::string const&s){return s.empty();}
```

Than let's look at symbol names:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c sample.cpp 
nm -C sample.o
```

We will see such symbols:

```
bar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
foo[abi:cxx11]()
C::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >[abi:cxx11]() const
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::empty() const
```

Function 'foo' is tagged - It is perfectly correct. In its name there is no sign of ABI, but it uses std::string which is dependent on ABI.

Function 'bar' is not tagged. And it is also OK as its signature has direct reference of ABI via std::__cxx11 namespace.

But 'operator std::string' is also tagged. Why? It has already 'std::__cxx11' in its name.

And 'std::string::empty' is not tagged. - Logical for me.

If we repeat same steps with clang++ (3.9, trunk from svn) we will see little bit different picture:

```
bar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
foo[abi:cxx11]()
C::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >() const
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::empty() const
```

Everything is the same but 'operator std::string'.

Who is right here g++ or clang++? I think that clang behavior is more logical.

However we already have some libraries compiled with g++ in various distributions of linux. So probably it is clang to be changed.

I have submitted this bug in llvm. But still have doubts - it is clang or gcc bug?

Comment: Just asking out of curiousity, why does it matter to you ?

Comment: This matters for me as i cannot compile my project with clang, only gcc.

Answer (score 1):

ABI tagging being a GCC feature that clang only emulates out of necessity, GCC is the a canonical reference.

Answer (score 1):

clang 4.0 and GCC 7.2 now produce the same mangled symbols:

```
bar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
foo[abi:cxx11]()
C::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >() const
```

It seems there was a mangling bug in GCC.

Comment: The "mangling bug" is "Mangling change for conversion operators" mentioned in https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-7/porting_to.html

Answer (score 0):

It's odd. clang 3.8 with https://reviews.llvm.org/D18035 worked correctly for me. That patch was mainlined in 3.9 yet it no longer works. I can't find any explanation.

```
undefined reference to `libconfig::Setting::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >() const
```

Comment: Also it looks like clang3.8 adds `__cxx11` but clang5.0.0 does not